# Qt on Visual Studio 2010 and win7 64bit

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

I decided to start working with Qt on my win7 (64bit). I downloaded and installed qt-win-opensource-4.8.4-vs2010.exe and the qt-vs-addin-1.1.11-opensource.exe.

Now  I can nun Qt projects on Win32, but I want or I need them on Win64 mode. When I try this I  get this error message

> there's no Qt version assigned to this project for platform x64 Please use the 'change the Qt version' feature and choose a valid Qt version for this platform.

Any idea how can I solve this.

Comment: Have you tried to "change the Qt version" and choose a valid Qt version for that platform?

Comment: yes I did but it didn't help

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK, you have to build Qt yourself to get a win64 version.

Comment: Yes, for Windows there is no 64-bit pre-built version to the best of my knowledge. The OP will have to take the sources and build them.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to build 64 bit code, you need to build Qt manually 64 bit version. qt-win-opensource-4.8.4-vs2010.exe only 32 bit.

Also you can use 32bit platform :) Ugly way is: open **Qt 4.8.3 Command Prompt** and run **devenv.exe** :D